# Multiple Replace conditions in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace, sql-update

I have a column named "Path" in a table called Purchase

```
\\fs01dsc.test.com\data\products\
\\ks01dsc.test.com\items\books\
```

I need to update the domain name for all values in this column like fs01dsc.test.com to xyz.com and also need to change the \\ to / and  \ to /.

So the expected output is

```
/xyz.com/data/products/
/xyz.com/Items/books/
```

Tried the below queries to update but it seems there would be a better apporoach that I'm not sure about

```
UPDATE Purchase
SET "PATH" =  LOWER(REPLACE("PATH", '\','/')) 

UPDATE Purchase
SET "PATH" = REPLACE("PATH", split_part("PATH" , '/', 3), 'xyz.com')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest your `replace` calls:

```sql
UPDATE Purchase
SET    "PATH" = 
       LOWER(REPLACE(REPLACE("PATH", split_part("PATH" , '/', 3), 'xyz.com'), '\', '/')
```

Comment: Thanks!! Updated query like this  "UPDATE purchase
SET  "PATH" = 
LOWER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE("PATH", split_part("PATH" , '\', 3), 'xyz.com'), '\', '/'),'//',''))